# how to create counter loop in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

can any tell me how can I write below code of c in django

```
for(c=0; c<5; c++)
  //do something
```

i had tried below code but it gives me an error

```
{% for(c=0; c<5; c++)%}
     <div class="tab-content">
    <h1 class="tab" title="title for page 1">Page 1</h1>
    <p>This is the content of tab 1 on container 1</p>
     </div>     
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: -1, at least. What on earth makes you think the Django template language is C? And this is all very clearly documented in the Django reference.

Comment: but i m getting error that is the reason I have to ask such silly que.. anyway if u can write this example then plzz suggest me

Comment: But why can't you look at the very good documentation? What's wrong with what you find there?

Comment: I had tried many examples given on web such as example given in http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5172 but I dont kn why I am getting error in these examples, and reason to write such question is reader can easily understand my question

Comment: That's a feature request, not documentation. Read what the header of the page says before using the examples.

Comment: @mahesh, you might want to take a look at this custom tag snippet - http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/

Comment: That ticket is not just a feature request, it's a feature request that's been closed as "not going to do it".  It's a wish denied.

Comment: Django's documentation is one of it's greatest features.  Here's your for loop from the docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Answer (score 4):

When you render your template, you may pass range

```
render_to_response('template_x.html', {'range5': range(5)})
```

And in html template, probably like this

```
{% for i in range5 %}
    <div class="tab-content">
    <h1 class="tab" title="title for page {{i}}">Page {{i}}</h1>
    <p>This is the content of tab {{i}} on container {{i}}</p>
    </div>  
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are not good at searching, right (:

[A good documentation for a good framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)... On the other hand, why you ask for a c-like loop structure in a framework written for python is another question

EDIT: For loop in django templates iterates through an array (or list in python terms). So you have to have a list to iterate.. In your related view, lets say yopu have a number list

```
number_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

if you pass this list to the template with the same name, then you can iterate through it with

```
{%for num in nuber_list%}
    Number is : {{num}}
{%endfor%}
```

But as i said, you have to pass that list to template in the return statement line that returns an httpresponse or render your contect to your template [as it described in here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)

Answer (score 3):

I was curious and found a way to do this. Disclaimer: I consider the following code to be *WRONG*:

```
{% for i in "abcde" %} do something {% endfor %}
```

Replace "abcde" with a string of the range you want.